# Плагин маски номеров стран для Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, плагин, wp-plugin

Нужен плагин для маски номеров стран. Вот как на этом сайте - https://mitridat-container.com/
Нашел аналоги, но там нет ограничения по кол-ву вводимых символов.  А кол-во цифр в разных странах может отличаться.
Если у кого-то есть название плагина или ссылка буду очень благодарен. Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Номера куда попало не вводятся. Это или готовый плагин (например контактной формы) или своя самопись. Что у тебя? Исправь вопрос добавив необходимую инфу.